# In GIMP 2.10 - How do I set it so that the background is always transparent and not a solid color?

Tags: graphics, gimp, image-processing

I just updated to GIMP 2.10 from 2.8 and I can't find the place to make the window always open with a transparent background.
Thanks!
Carol

Comment: Hi @casnavy, welcome! Just so you know, you might get a better answer at [the Graphic Design Stack Exchange](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean the transparency checkerboard, see `Edit>Preferences>Display>Transparency>Check styles`.

If you want the "Background" layer to be transparent in new images:

- for the default image: see `Edit>Preferences>Default image>Advanced options (click to unfold)>Fill with` (and set to `Transparency` of course):

[image]

- if you use image templates, set the background fill for these templates:

[image]

Comment: Again, THANK YOU xenoid!  You have become my GIMP savior!!  You are making my week so much easier!  I am stuck away from home b/c of covid-19, and my main computer I use. I am trying to set up my laptop the same way my computer at home is set up.   Thanks again!!!!!

Comment: YAY!  Was able to set it to default image "fill with transparency"                              
                                                                                                                                  
NOTE to others trying to do this:  REMEMBER, you always have to restart GIMP to get the changes you made.  So it won't show up as auto transparent layer until you close GIMP and start it up again.

Comment: Setting the Default New Image fill to Transparency still opens a new image with WHITE. (I changed my foreground and background color but makes no difference) I restarted GIMP 2.10 after the changes. Did a Reset in the Preferences and that fixed it but can anyone tell me why that happens?

Comment: Works for me, but you also have to *not* select a template. If you select a template, then the fill used is the one set in the template.